# Multiply a range of numbers - Python2.x

Tags: python, python-2.7

I apologize for the beginner question, I'm teaching myself. I've done some searching and have only found factorials. What I'm looking for is, given a range(2, 10) to multiply all of those numbers out:

In the above example of 2-10 we would have something like this:

> 2 * 1 = 2
>
> 2 * 2 = 4
>
> ...
>
> 3 * 1 = 3
>
> 3 * 2 = 4

...

and so on, until you've gone through your list.

What I have:

```
def product(number):
    for i in range(2,10):
        return number * i

for number in range(2,10):
    print product(number)
```

This only seems to work for my 2 case. so I get to 18 and it doesn't go back through and move to the next integer.

Comment: Looks like you need to add a counter for the `i` variable..

Comment: Move the return statement outside your loop. `for i in range(2, 10): return number * i` only runs once, because `return` breaks your loop. Alternatively change `return` to `yield` and baby, you got a generator goin'!

Comment: @Dave, yield ->  http://pastebin.com/Bbij1cRz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you return the value on the first iteration and so your loop never gets exausted.

You could either do it as a [`generator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), which is better, as suggested in the comments, or you could simply return the list of value with a list comprehension:

```
def product(number):
    return [number * i for i in range(2, 10)]
```

You could of course ditch the function in this case, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: Someone's going to have to 'splain this generator thing to me, at some point! :)

Comment: It is a lovely thing, but probably not the best thing to learn as a begginer (not sure about your background). The [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/) are a lovely way to get a comprehensive explaination of most concepts. Additionally, Stack Overflow has some great answers, search for them, you won't regret it!

Comment: @DaveKalaluhi You can oversimplify a generator to thinking of it as being functionally equivalent to a list, but rather than knowing **all the values at once**, it only knows how to produce the next value you're going to ask for. Advantages: memory consumption is way lower, possibly faster to use; disadvantages: can't be reused, not as flexible as lists in some cases.

Comment: Changing your return line to the following will convert it to using generators: `return (number * i for i in xrange(2, 10))`. Note brackets, `[]`, changed to parentheses and `range` changed to `xrange` which returns a generator.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning before you complete the loop in side your product() function.

```
def product(number):
    out = []
    for i in range(2,10):
        out.append(number * i)
    return out

for number in range(2,10):
    print(product(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def product(number):
    for i in range (2, 10):
        print("{} * {} = {}".format(i, number, (i * number)))

for n in range(2, 10):
    product(n)
```

This will perform the same function but is a bit cleaner.  The formatting is for python 3.x but it will work in 2.x.

by using the .format method you get to see what is being multiplied as well as the results.

As others have pointed out though, a generator is an even better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
for x, y in itertools.product(xrange(2, 10), xrange(2, 10)):
    print '{} * {} = {}'.format(x, y, x*y)
```